# Difference between "using MyNameSpace;" and "namespace MyNameSpace"

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, using

Hello I am new to asp.net. I am confused what is the difference between "using MyNameSpace;" and "namespace MyNameSpace". My demo code is as follow...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

> using **MyNameSpace**;
>
> namespace **MyNameSpace**

```
{
    public partial class DemoPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        My code here
    }
}
```

In the above code is there any difference between the two highlighted statements or not. If yes then what is it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they provide complementary services.

A using directive like this:

```
using MyNamespace;
```

Tells the compiler to look in the namespace `MyNamespace` when resolving simple names - so if you have a type called `MyNamespace.Foo`, you can just use `Foo` in your source to refer to it when you've got this using directive.

However, the namespace *declaration* effectively says, "Anything I declare within this block is in the given namespace". So to *declare* the `MyNamespace.Foo` type, you'd use:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Foo
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Do you see? The `using` directive says that you want to *use* things in a particular namespace, whereas the namespace declaration is about putting things *into* a particular namespace.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the nice explanation. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

`using` is used for creating a "shortcut" to typenames within that namespace. This is only needed when the code you write is within another namespace. `namespace` is used for *defining*  a namespace:

**Example**
In file `first.cs`:

```
// define the namespace "SomeNamespace"
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    // define a type within the namespace
    class SomeClass { }
}
```

In file `second.cs`:

```
using SomeNamespace;
// define the namespace "OtherNamespace"
namespace OtherNamespace
{
    class OtherClass
    {
        void SomeMethod()
        {
            // use the type "SomeClass", defined in the "SomeNamespace" namespace
            // note that without the using directive above we would need to write
            // SomeNamespace.SomeClass for this to work.
            SomeClass temp = new SomeClass();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code sample, the declaration of the `temp` variable does not need to include the namespace, since it is mentioned in a `using` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference. The `namespace` statement is used to create a namespace, while the `using` statement is used to make the compiler regognise an already existing namespace.

In your code the `using` statement has no effect, as all your code is in that namespace so it already knows about it.

As you have `using System.Web.UI`, the `System.Web.UI.Page` identifier could be written as just `Page` as the compiler knows about the classes in that namespace. If you wouldn't have that `using` statement, you would need the fully qualified name for the compiler to know where to find the class.